# Add Values to Specific cells in DataGridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a select query which reads a number from a table and counts its occurrence and display it in a datagridview. I have the following code but all it does it show me the last number and its count.

For example the last number in the loop is 30, so it will show number 30 in the datagridview and along with its count lets say 10, what I want to do is to view all the numbers from 1-30 and its count and display it in the datagridview.

```cs
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView8.Rows)
{
    if (!row.IsNewRow)
    {
        for (int nu = 1; nu < 70; nu++)
        {
            string query = "Select count(*) from [AllData] where [Num2]=@Num2 And [Cd_Name]=@Cd_Name ";                                                                                                              
            SqlCeCommand cmd1 = new SqlCeCommand(query, con1);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Num2", nu);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cd_Name", ab);
            cnt = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
            cmd1.ExecuteReader();                           
            row.Cells[2].Value = nu.ToString();
            row.Cells[3].Value = cnt.ToString();                           
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the how the datagridview looks like.

```
 Col_1  Col_2
    70   0                              
    70   0                              
    70   0                              
    70   0                              
    70   0                              
    70   0                              
    70   0                              
    70   0                              
    70   0                              
    70   0
```

What I want to do is in column 1 display the number and in column 2 display the total count of the number from the db.

Comment: Sorry I  could not understand .Whether you want to change a number of wows od a column from the grid or something else

Comment: @LDS , i have edited the question to show what the output of the gridview looks like, 

what i want to do is in column 1 display the number and in column 2 display the total count of the number from the db.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not aware of your table structure and data. As per my understanding

```js
string query = "Select count(*) from [AllData] where [Num2]=@Num2 And [Cd_Name]=@Cd_Name ";                                                                                                              
                            SqlCeCommand cmd1 = new SqlCeCommand(query, con1);
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Num2", nu);
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cd_Name", ab);
                            cnt = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
                       var cnt = cmd1.ExecuteScalar(); 
                            
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView8.Rows)
    {
        if (!row.IsNewRow)
        {    
          row.Cells[2].Value = nu.ToString();
          row.Cells[3].Value = cnt.ToString();                          
         }
    }
```

Comment: it ends up giving the same output as my original query, it all the rows have last number with its occurrence instead of all the numbers and its occurrences

Comment: from my under standing you need the counts of rows group by cd_name.If so the query will be changed and loop will be changed